# Mostrar resultado de la resta de fechas en pantalla, he tratado de visualizar el resultado y me genera error o simplemente no lo muestra en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Aca la consulta

```
for BBDDEscuela in elUsuario:
    miID.set(BBDDEscuela[0])
    miNombre1.set(BBDDEscuela[1])
    miNombre2.set(BBDDEscuela[2])
    miApellido1.set(BBDDEscuela[3])
    miApellido2.set(BBDDEscuela[4])
    miSexo.set(BBDDEscuela[5])
    miFecha=(BBDDEscuela[6])
    c=miFecha
```

Llamada de función para calcular días

```
Calculo_Dias(c)
miConexion.commit()
```

Aquí la función para calcular días

```
def Calculo_Dias(b):
    a=datetime.datetime.today()
    f=datetime.datetime.strptime(str(b), '%Y-%m-%d')
    miDias=(a-f)
    k=miDias.days
    miDias=int(k)
```

Aquí muestro en pantalla

```
cuadroDias=Entry(miFrame1, width=30, textvariable=miDias, state=DISABLED)
cuadroDias.grid(row=4, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)
```

Me pueden ayudar quizás es simple pero llevo una semana tratando de resolverlo y no he podido.

Comment: Hola Juan, para empezar `miDias` tiene que ser una `StringVar` no un entero como es en `Calculo_Dias`. Teniendo esto, bastaría con hacer `miDias.set((a-f).days)` aunque debes temporalmente habilitar el Entry.  Por otro lado las etiquetas `python-3.x` y `python-2.7` no deberían usarse conjuntamente , además falta añadir la etiqueta `tkinter` ¿que versión de python usas realmente?

Comment: Muchas Gracias, uso las versión 3.8.1, estoy aprendiendo, como habilito temporalmente el Entry? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, ya hice el cambio y me funciono, excelente solución, mil gracias